# Can Android Applications ( using libraries build from NDK ) be used on both x86 & ARM platform?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am going to build an Android application in which I want to use a C library. So, I am planning to use NDK along with the SDK. NDK supports ARMv5, ARmv7 and x86  instruction set. Now, if I build an Android application using ARMv5 , will it run on Android phones based on Intel ( x86 ) platform (am I missing something ?)? If not, then what is the way by which I can build an ANdroid application ( which uses some C libraries underneath ) that can run on all the Android phones irrespective of the underneath platform?

Vibgyor

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the following command in ndk to build .so for the architecture.

```
./ndk-build APP_ABI=armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

The .so will be present in the respective directory and will be picked up at runtime.

So you need to build your NDK portion for every cpu. So in the end you will end up with a .so file for arm, one for x86 (and maybe another one for armv7).

The two / three .so files are bundled in your final .apk, and during installation the Android OS picks the right .so file for the device it's being installed on.

So if you have a java portion: that will run on everything.
If you have a NDK portion: You will need to create a .so file for every cpu platform, but they can / will be bundled together and automaticly picked without the user knowing what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to build the native library for all platforms (armeabi armeabi-v7a mips and x86), just set "all" in the variable APP_ABI.

jni/Application.mk

> APP_ABI := **all**
>   APP_PLATFORM := android-8

In my case, I use android-ndk-r9b

Note: If you are deploying native libraries to x86 and MIPS-based devices, your application must target Android 2.3 (API level 9) or later.

AndroidManifest.xml

> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

More info: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Some x86 devices, e.g. Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, include an arm emulation layer. This is important to know, but you should follow the advice above in your work. One reason why you should not rely on this emulation if possible is that performance is about 40% of economies code.